# The right way to create custom sub-elements with X-Tag

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, x-tag

So I know the [x-tag web component library](http://x-tag.github.io/) enables you create custom elements that appear in HTML like this:

```
<x-my-custom-element>my content</x-my-custom-element>
```

However, what if I wanted to create multiple custom sub-elements, like this:

```
<x-my-custom-element>
    <x-my-custom-element-child>
        <x-my-custom-element-grandchild></x-my-custom-element-grandchild>
    </x-my-custom-element-child>
</x-my-custom-element>
```

Is the right way to simply call `xtag.register()` three times, like so:

```
xtag.register('x-my-custom-element', {...});
xtag.register('x-my-custom-element-child', {...});
xtag.register('x-my-custom-element-grandchild', {...});
```

Also, is there any way to *force* a sub-element to always be a child of another element? In other words, this would work:

```
<x-my-custom-element-parent>
    <x-my-custom-element-child></x-my-custom-element-child>
</x-my-custom-element-parent>
```

but this wouldn't:

```
<x-my-custom-element-child>
    <x-my-custom-element-parent></x-my-custom-element-parent>
</x-my-custom-element-child>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your custom element names are valid (contain a "dash" `-` character), you would only need to register them with `xtag.register()` if you need to add functionality, attributes, default content, shadow DOM, etc.  Elements with unrecognized but valid names will simply be `HTMLElement` objects.  Elements with unrecognized and invalid names will be `HTMLUnknownElement` objects.

```
// valid custom element name
document.createElement('foo-bar') instanceof HTMLElement; // true

// invalid custom element name
document.createElement('foobar') instanceof HTMLUnknownElement; // true
```

You can read the [WHATWG Spec for HTMLUnknownElement here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlunknownelement).

I don't know of any way to force element hierarchy.  Standard HTML elements don't enforce this.  For example, you can do `<li><ul></ul></li>` and `<source><video></source>`.  The elements simply don't function when used improperly like this.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question as it probably wasn't clear what I was referring to by x-tag. Regarding the *forceful* compliance, I want to `console.warn` when the sub-element is being used improperly. However, I think I can implement functionality to do this inside x-tag.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill You could look at the `tagName` of the `parentNode` in the `inserted` lifecycle function, and do a `console.warn()` if it's not what you expect:

    xtag.register('custom-child', {
        lifecycle: {
            inserted() {
                if ('custom-parent' !== this.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase())
                    console.warn('<custom-child> should be child of <custom-parent>')
            }
        }
    })

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot register 3 different custom elements with the same prototype.

So you'll need to create 3 different prototypes, for example with `Object.create()`:

```
protoChild = Object.create( protoParent )
protoGrandchild = Object.create( protoChild )
```

Then call `regsiter()` method.

Regarding your second question, you'll need to control yourself the content of your custom element, when the element is *created* of *attached*.

Comment: I was referring to the [x-tag](http://x-tag.github.io/) web component library (see update). I'm not quite sure how your answer fits into that.